# asp.net getting the url parameter and putting it in textbox value

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page which has a form in it with a `TextBox`, when I press enter it redirects me to `Results.aspx?srch=search_term` and I want to give that `TextBox` the searched term. The problems is that the `Results.aspx.cs` doesn't see the `ID` of the Masterpage's `TextBox`. Is there any other method to achieve this?

This is the Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.Master.cs" Inherits="Groups.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jq.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <h2><a href="Default.aspx">Groups</a></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
                            <div class="form-group search input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="search" placeholder="Cauta grup..." class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 text-right">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <% if (Session["uid"] == null) { %>
                                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
                            <% } else { %>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%= Session["uname"]  %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="addgroup.aspx">Add group</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            <%} %>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="header" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <div class="container">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="subheader" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <span>Copyright &copy; 2015 Groups</span>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and this it the `Results.aspx` behindcode, the problem is here `search.Text = Request.QueryString["srch"];`, `search` doesn't exist in `Results.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["srch"]))
            {
                String srch = Request.QueryString["srch"];
                search.Text = Request.QueryString["srch"];

                //perform search and display results
                String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GroupsConnString"].ToString();

                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

                conn.Open();
                queryStr = "";
                queryStr = "SELECT g.*,CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) as name FROM app_groups.groups g LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = g.id_user WHERE group_name LIKE '%" + srch + "%' OR group_type LIKE '%" + srch + "%'";
                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                gname = "";//group name
                gtype = "";//group type
                uname = "";//user name
                id = "";
                warning = "";
                id_owner = "";

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
                    {
                        uname = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
                        gname = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("group_name"));
                        gtype = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("group_type"));
                        id = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
                        id_owner = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("id_user"));
                        warning = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("warning"));

                        Panel pan = new Panel();
                        pan.CssClass = "col-sm-4 group";
                        if ((Session["uid"] != null && Session["uadmin"].Equals("1")) || id_owner.Equals(Session["uid"]))
                        {
                            adminCtrls = new Panel();
                            adminCtrls.CssClass = "adminCtrls";
                            btn = new Button();//delete group button for admins only
                            btn.Click += new EventHandler(deleteGroup);
                            btn.ID = "sterge";
                            btn.CssClass = "btn btn-danger btn-xs";
                            btn.Text = "Sterge grup";
                            btn.CommandArgument = id;
                            //btn.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right;");
                            adminCtrls.Controls.Add(btn);

                            if (Session["uadmin"].Equals("1"))
                            {
                                if (!warning.Equals("1"))
                                {
                                    btn = new Button();//warn owner button for admins only
                                    btn.Click += new EventHandler(warnOwner);
                                    btn.ID = "warn";
                                    btn.CssClass = "btn btn-warning btn-xs";
                                    btn.Text = "Avertizeaza owner grup";
                                    btn.CommandArgument = id;
                                    adminCtrls.Controls.Add(btn);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    btn = new Button();//warn owner button for admins only
                                    btn.ID = "warn";
                                    btn.Enabled = false;
                                    btn.CssClass = "btn btn-warning btn-xs";
                                    btn.Text = "A fost avertizat";
                                    adminCtrls.Controls.Add(btn);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (adminCtrls != null)
                        {
                            pan.Controls.Add(adminCtrls);
                        }
                        pan.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='title text-center'>" + gname + "</span><br/>"));
                        pan.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>Owner: <span class='owner'>" + uname + "</span></span><br/>"));
                        pan.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span>Categorie: <span class='type'>" + gtype + "</span></span><br/>"));
                        groupsShow.Controls.Add(pan);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you do it in MasterPage's page load? you can retrieve the same `Request.QueryString["srch"]` there too. check if it is null, and if not, set it to the textbox.

Comment: As an aside, and I appreciate this is unrelated to your question - but just to point out that your queryStr variable is building sql by string concatenation, which is begging for sql injection attacks. It might be worth looking at doing this with parameters rather than string concetenation.

Comment: @PulseLab I know that, this is for a school project, I don't have time nor the energy to read a bit in order to do this the proper way, if it works, then it's good, the professor won't test if for SQL injections :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference a control that's provided by your master page, you can get to it using Master.FindControl("..."), i.e. :

```
var myControl = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("search");
```

Comment: and how do I pass the url paramater value to myControl's value afterwards ?

Comment: In the above example, myControl is now a reference to that TextBox object. So you can then do: myControl.Text = Request.QueryString["srch"];